# How to copy clone folder to remote computer in one line?

Tags: command-line, bash, ssh, rsync

I have two machines with the same folder structure. One is my personal computer, the other is a remote computer. Sometimes I want a program to run on the remote computer.
At the moment I always need to

1. ssh to the remote computer
2. Type my password
3. copy the folder manually using rsync

Even if I would write a script for rsync (like the one shown below) I would still need to enter my password every time or hard code it inside the bash script (which would be stupid).

```
#!/bin/bash/
pathToSync="/path/to/my/Folder/"
rsync -r -l -p --progress "$pathToSync"/ myUsername@nameOfRemoteComputer:"$pathToSync"
```

Has someone an idea of how to solve this problem more efficiently?
Such that in the end I only need to write

```
sync myFolder nameOfRemoteComputer
```

The question has been answered.
As Addition to the correct answer given below. Here are the the bash commands to make `ssh` and `rsync` work without having to enter passwords. On the client computer type:

mkdir ~/.ssh # Maybe this folder already exists
  chmod 700 ~/.ssh
  cd ~/.ssh
  ssh-keygen -t rsa # This creates a public key
  cp authorized_keys authorized_keys_Backup # This backups old / existing keys 
  cat id_rsa.pub >>~/.ssh/authorized_keys
  ssh-copy-id nameOfRemoteComputer

Done! (-> Check if ssh works without password now)
(I have the same username on client and remote computer otherwise it would be `ssh-copy-id myRemoteUsername@nameOfRemoteComputer`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### SCP

Since you have ssh access you can just use command `scp` to do your work.

In terminal enter:

`scp -r /path/to/my/folder myUsername@nameOfRemoteComputer:/path/to/my/folder`

If you also use the same username on both computers you can even ommit `myUsername@` and just enter:

`scp -r /path/to/my/folder nameOfRemoteComputer:/path/to/my/folder`

The name of the remote copumter can be an IP, a domain name or a name assigned at `/etc/hosts`.

### Avoid Entering Password for SSH Connection

You could setup an SSH Key Pair between your server and your local machine.

I would suggest you use [Passwords and Keyes](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/quantal/seahorse/) app. It should come pre-installed on Ubuntu.

[image]

### New Key Pair

Press the green <kbd>+</kbd> and create a new **Secure Shell Key**. Follow the dialog boxes to create a new key pair.

[Here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSH/OpenSSH/Keys) you can find terminal commands to generate the key pair `id_rsa` and `id_rsa.pub`, you will need to get a copy of `id_rsa.pub` to your server to make the key pair work.

Add the contents of `id_rsa.pub` to the file `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` at your server in a new line. You could use command: `cat id_rsa.pub >>~/.ssh/authorized_keys` after login in through ssh.

If you set a passphrase to the private key you will have to enter the passphrase to ulock it. Assign no passphrase for ease of use.

Comment: But also in that case I would have to enter my password manually right?

Comment: You would need to use your password. You can set up an ssh-key to your remote server to avoid having to enter a password every-time. It is generally stronger than using a password you can remember and it will also make it so that you don't have to enter a password anymore. Are both of your machines using Ubuntu?

Comment: Yes. They both run Ubuntu

Comment: Thanks, that worked :). I will add the commands I had to execute in my question above...